# How can I disable offline dino starvation?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I have a server that I want to leave on 24/7 but my whole tribe has been offline for months so I shut it down to save the dinos.

There is a "Food Drain" setting in "Dino Settings" which can technically be set to '0' but I'm not sure what affect that will have on taming.

Is there some combination of settings that still allows for a fairly normal taming experience yet prevents tamed dinos from starving when the tribe is offline?

Answer (score 3):

The `DinoCharacterFoodDrainMultiplier`-parameter does influence the taming-speed, because the unconcious dinos also use this parameter (with another one) to calculate their food-drain. To compensate the longer taming time you could increase the `TamingSpeedMultiplier` in a reciprocal way. That is not possible if you set the food-drain to zero, of course.

I don't know, how the taming-experience will change. It could be with extremely changed values that a dino will not eat for a long time, then eat one piece and get tamed. Making the taming time similar, but the taming experience will be different.

Also see this post on the steam-forums for the same question: https://steamcommunity.com/app/346110/discussions/0/530647080129304242/

To solve your original problem: How about just shut down the server for some time? Or save the world and if you reconnect after a long time load that savefile again. That would solve the issue without having to manipulate the settings.

Comment: I'd like to leave it up 24/7 so more folks start coming in and playing.